# 5 equal width columns in bootstrap (full width of container)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

According to my psd template, i have CONTAINER which consists of 5 equal width (344px) columns. I decided to go with bootstrap in terms of responsiveness. But now i'm frustrated with this task.

Is there any way to implement this or i need:

- Rebuild my psd template to fit bootstrap grid and sizes
- Not to use bootstrap and write custom responsive classes

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZbBQG

```
<div class="cont">
        <div class="bicycles">
          <div class="bik"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637925/v637925758/4d271/da6RN5KLBRU.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="bik"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637925/v637925758/4d271/da6RN5KLBRU.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="bik"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637925/v637925758/4d271/da6RN5KLBRU.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="bik"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637925/v637925758/4d271/da6RN5KLBRU.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="bik"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637925/v637925758/4d271/da6RN5KLBRU.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: They aren't going to be responsive? It's going to be a 1720px wide row?

Comment: @MichaelCoker exactly. I want it to be responsive, so when you scale down rowser width - 1 row will consists of 3-4 columns, instead of 5 and so on.

Comment: @Src alright, just updated my answer. is that what you're going for?

Comment: @MichaelCoker it seems like what i'm looking for, but now i have a problem: when you scale down width of browser window and cross the break point - there are some free space after 4 column. I'm probably need to make container 100% content size?

Comment: @Src there will be space after the last column if the columns are fixed width. How do you want it to behave instead? It would help if you could figure out what you need before posting a question, and make sure your post has a clear description of your end goal.

Comment: @MichaelCoker As i wrote earlier, when you pass breakpoint,  1 row consists of 4 instead of 5 columns, BUT container resizes to size of it's content. That is how i think i might solve problem of that free space.

Comment: @ZimSystem Just read comments, i've already answered to the similar question.

Comment: @ZimSystem I made codepen. This is what i wanted to achieve with bootstrap: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZbBQG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using the auto layout `col-lg` columns for larger widths so that you can have 5 across, then scale down to the standard size grid columns on `md`, `sm`, etc..

**Bootstrap 4.6 (update 2020)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block">
           <!--force wrap every 5 on lg-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: This will allow the columns to grow evenly to fill the width of the row. In rare cases where the column content forces the width (for example columns that contain fixed width images or non-wrapping text), use `min-width:0` to force equal column width regardless of their content.

```
.col-lg {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/DVzExqdUZa

Comment: Can i use custom column width with this type of layout? Or should i use just flexbox without bootstrap for this kind of things?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is flexbox so I don't see the need for the custom classes.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as it has still flex-grow property being set to 1 which will make them smaller or bigger depending on their content size.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt apparently the OP considered it to be the correct answer because they had similar sized column content. With flex-grow: 1 the columns won't fill the width across so your critique isn't valid. This is a broader flexbox issue that has been addressed before and to force equal width min-width: 0 would be set. I suggest not downvoting when your reasoning is vague, subjective and based on an edge case that's outside the scope of the OP question.

Comment: @zim Thanks for updating your code. It is upvoted now.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy using bootstrap 4. You just need a single `flex` line on the columns to define the custom width.

```css
.row > .col {
  flex: 0 0 344px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Flexbox. I suggest you to use 1200px or less as the maximum container width.

```
<div class="container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
</div>

.container{

    display: flex;
    width: 1720px;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can customize your version of bootstrap "the right way". The link to this page let's you customize A LOT of settings, including the number of grid columns.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/